# Sybase DBA learning resources

Tags: sybase

Does Sybase provide learning resources for wannabe Sybase DBAs like Oracle Learn by Example?

I am an experienced relational DBA wanting to learn Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

Sybase DBA must read:

- Sybook http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp
- http://sypron.nl/
- http://rocket99.com/sybase/

Comment: stupid antispam system=\